# HDF5 :pandas: error opening file in read only mode while mode used is 'w'

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

Hello i am trying to save the dataframe in .h5 file but while i am providing command to do that, it fails saying that file is opening in read only mode and file does not exist.

```
table.to_hdf('test.h5', key= 'csdkc', mode='w')
```

I looked for question on stack over but nothing looked relevant.

Comment: where's your file located, and where is your script located? I bet if you provide full path (ie. `/users/nats/something/somewhere/test.h5`) it will work.

Comment: well 'w' is a write mode so it should create a file i belive of name test.h5 if i am not wrong

Comment: Is this also the name of a file you are currently reading from?

Comment: I am using the dataframe to read the data which is table in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
table.to_hdf('test.h5', 'csdkc', table=True, mode='a')
```

Take a look at this example

WRITE

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'jh':[9,2,3,2],'dp':[1,0,0,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'jh':[7,1,2,1],'dp':[1,8,1,1]})

df1.to_hdf('newf.h5', 'ks',table=True)
df2.to_hdf('newf.h5', 'ks',table=True)
```

READ

```
import pandas as pd

print (pd.read_hdf('newf.h5', 'ks',table=True))
```

Output

```
python a52.py 
   dp  jh
0   1   7
1   8   1
2   1   2
3   1   1
```

Mode is optional, so something else is wrong in your case.

Comment: I tried mode as a and i also tried modes as r+ as well but it failed for all of them with same error messge. The problem is while using mode as w it should not say opening file in read only mode.  apperantly for mode as a file should be there.